# I am to run python FastAPI locally, but when trying to run through container, not getting any response on browser. No error as well

Tags: python, docker, containers, fastapi

I am able to run python FastAPI locally(connecting to local host http://127.0.0.1:8000/), but when I am trying to run through container, not getting any response on browser. No error message either.

content of main.py

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Optional[str] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

content of Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.5

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./docker_req.txt /code/docker_req.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/docker_req.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

output on cmd when running container:-

```
docker run --name my-app1 python-fastapi:1.5
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/code']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [7]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

docker_req.txt --

```
fastapi==0.73.0
pydantic==1.9.0
uvicorn==0.17.4
```

Comment: What `docker run` command do you use to run it?

Comment: ^^ this is the correct question. If you are not passing in ports to map from your local to the docker container, your webserver will not be reachable on your machine's localhost.

Comment: `docker run --expose 8000 ...` and later you have to find containser ID (`docker ps`) and use it to get IP of this docker (`docker inspect <ContainerID> | grep IPAddress`). And later use this IP to access server in docker. At my computer it is `http://172.17.0.2:8000`

Comment: This is my run command-
run --name my-app5 -p 8000:8000 python-fastapi:1.5
I also tried as
run --name my-app5 -p 8080:8080 python-fastapi:1.5

I understood that ithis error has to do with docker network but couldn't solve i.

Answer (score 5):

Insert `-d` before docker run to run your container in Detached mode. try to run:

`docker run -d --name my-app5 -p 8000:8000 python-fastapi:1.5`

Comment: Finally found a solution so thank you. But that being said, why does this work?

Comment: This answer is misleading, `-d` does not make a difference. It is `-p` (port mapping) that is making  the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler: you can redirect local port `8000` to docker port `8000`

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 ...
```

and now you can access it using one of

- `http://0.0.0.0:8000`
- `http://localhost:8000`
- `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

---

Longer: you can expose port `8000` and run it using docker `IP`

```
docker run --expose 8000 ...
```

or in `Dockerfile` you can use `EXPOSE 8000`

Next you have to find `Container ID`

```
docker ps
```

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
0e7c6c543246   furas/fastapi   "uvicorn app.main:ap…"   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   8000/tcp   stupefied_nash
```

or

```
docker ps -q
```

```
0e7c6c543246
```

And use (part of) `CONTAINER ID` to get container IP address

```
docker inspect 0e7c | grep IPAddress
```

```
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

or

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 0e7c
```

```
172.17.0.2
```

And now you can access it using

- `http://172.17.0.2:8000`

---

**EDIT:**

In one line (on Bash)

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -q)
```

```
172.17.0.2
```

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is unusable except on one very specific setup (calling from outside a container on a native-Linux host; not usable from other hosts, on MacOS, or on Docker Desktop, Minikube, Docker Toolbox, _etc._).  I would not advise looking it up or trying to use it.  The `docker run -p` option works everywhere and is the right approach.

Comment: @DavidMaze good to know. I use only Linux host.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating yaml file and running it via docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-app:
    image: python-fastapi:1.5
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

In yaml file, I also tried without ports and it still worked whereas the below docker run command not working

```
docker run --name my-app5 -p 8000:8000 python-fastapi:1.5
```

Can anyone pls explain why its not working from "docker run" command but working from yaml file?